# Show date on x-axis only at midnight

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a dataset which lasts over several days and on the x-axis only the time in hours and minutes is visible:

```
tickloc = [datenum('27-Aug-2016 18:00:00'):2/24:datenum('31-Aug-2016 13:00:00')];
set(gca,'xtick',tickloc,'xlim',[datenum('27-Aug-2016 18:00:00') datenum('31-Aug-2016 13:00:00')])   
ax = gca; ax.XTickLabelRotation = 0;  
datetick('x','HH:MM','keepticks')
```

Is there any proper solution to display the date of the specific day on the x-axis as well? Preferably only once at midnight when the next day starts so that it becomes obvious to which day the data belongs.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can select just the `tickloc` where the `hour` is `0` and use those as your tick locations.

```
set(ax, 'XTick', tickloc(hour(tickloc) == 0), 'XLim', tickloc([1 end]))
```

Also you can use a custom date string for `datetick` so just specify the date

```
datetick('x', 'mm/dd/yyyy', 'keepticks')
```

You can then set the minor ticks using the `Ruler` of the x axis

```
ax.XRuler.MinorTickValues = tickloc;
ax.XRuler.MinorTick = 'on';
```

[image]